# Own geojson data in Mapbox are not displayed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to fill my mapbox with data from a database. I'm building a geojson from data and I'm using this as the source in the map. However, I get the error in the debugger:

> Error {message: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'length')"}

. If I use Mapbox's example URL: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson everything works without errors.

```
 const getData = useCallback(async () => {
 const points = Promise.all(
  alleArtikel?.map((artikel) => ({
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {
      userId: artikel.userId,
      userBild: artikel.userBild,
      artikelId: artikel._id,
      anzahl: alleArtikel?.length,
    },
    geometry: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [
        parseFloat(artikel.long).toFixed(4),
        parseFloat(artikel.lat).toFixed(4),
      ],
    },
  }))
);

setPoints(await points);
}, []);


useEffect(() => {
 if (points.length)
   map.on("load", () => {
      map.addSource("users", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: { points }, //message in Debugger: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"
        cluster: true,
        clusterMaxZoom: 14, 
        clusterRadius: 50, 
      });

   ...
    })
   }, [points]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet seems a bit incomplete (what is `setPoints()` for instance), but two things look wrong:

1. An array of `Feature` is not a valid GeoJSON object. You need to wrap it in a `FeatureCollection` object. See the GeoJSON spec.
2. `data: { points }`  looks wrong: that would pass an object with a single member called `points`.

You probably want something like:

```
data: {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: points
}
```